# How can I insert text in a text widget from another class in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter

I'm trying to access a tkinter text widget from another class through instancing, but it's not being modified when called from outside class but works fine when the method is called inside the class.

I've also tried @staticmethod, though that doesn't seem to work either. I'd much prefer using an instanced object of the class though.

So here's the main:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainapp = tk.Tk()
    mainapp.title("Automatic Proofreader")
    mainapp.configure(background = "gray")
    mainapp.resizable(width = False, height = False)
    Core(mainapp).grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = 'news')
    TextDisplay(mainapp).grid(column = 5, row = 0, sticky = 'news')
    mainapp.mainloop()
```

Here's the class and the method I need to access:

```
class TextDisplay(tk.Frame):

    def setText(self, text):
        self.displayout.config(state = "normal")
        self.displayout.delete(1.0, tk.END)
        #This inserts nothing when called from outside class
        self.displayout.insert(tk.INSERT, text)
        #But it inserts the correct text when called from this same class
        self.displayout.config(state = "disabled")

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        verticalscroll = tk.Scrollbar(self)

        self.displayout = tk.Text(self, font = ('comic sans', 20, 'bold'), height = 20, width = 40, bg = "gray", wrap = tk.WORD, yscrollcommand = verticalscroll.set, state= "disabled")
        self.displayout.grid(columnspan = 4)

        verticalscroll.grid(column = 5, sticky = 'ns')
        verticalscroll.config(command = self.displayout.yview)
```

I'm first instancing this in another class like so `self.displayclass = TextDisplay(mainapp)`

and calling the method like so `self.displayclass.setText(self.text)`

I noticed in debugging, that the value of `text` variable *inside* the method is passed perfectly when called from outside the class (e.g `self.text` gets passed correctly as `text`). But the insertion does not work.

EDIT : By "not working" I meant that, it does not insert anything at all. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: re: _"I'm first instancing this in another class like so self.displayclass = TextDisplay(mainapp)"_ - that is not what the code in your question does. Also, please define what _"does not work"_ means - does it insert the wrong text? Does it insert the text into the wrong widget? Does it throw an error? If it throws an error, what's the error?

Comment: So you're creating a *second* instance of `TextDisplay`, setting the text of *that*, and somehow expecting this to appear in the original instance?  That might work with a voodoo doll, it doesn't work with computer programs.

Comment: @jasonharper: I don't think the voodoo doll comment is appropriate for this site. It's a bit too condescending.

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry, I thought "it's not being modified" would be clear but I meant that it's not inserting anything, though now I understand that as jasonharper said, I'm not modifying the value of the *actual* class but the second instance. How can I modify the value of the actual class then?

Comment: @Chase: like my answer shows, to modify the value of the actual class, you need a reference to the actual class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, to call a function on an object you must have a reference to an instance of the object. That's a fundamental aspect of object-oriented programming.

You don't necessarily have to use a global variable. You can, or you can store it as an attribute on some other object.

Here is a minimal example that works:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainapp = tk.Tk()
    displayclass = TextDisplay(mainapp)
    displayclass.grid(column = 5, row = 0, sticky = 'news')

    displayclass.setText("hello, world")
    mainapp.mainloop()
```

Comment: I suppose I could use displayclass as a global variable like so, but is there a way to directly modify the value of the textwidget of this class without declaring it as a global variable?

Comment: @Chase: to call a method on an object, you need a reference to the object. That's a fundamental aspect of object-oriented programming. It doesn't have to be global, it could be an attribute on another class, passed around as an argument, etc.